# Angular 8 Convert an existing angular Application to Library

Tags: angular, angular8

I have  an Angular project with multiple components. I want to convert it into Library. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the links in official angulario as per given

[creating libs](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

and let me know if you have any specific requirments.

Comment: moreover there are plenty of video tutorials there on youtube also

Comment: this link is about creating a library and then angular project in it. But have an angular project and I want to convert it into library.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about whole project conversion but you can definitely create libraries for components. 
[refer link](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1576823510060000&usg=AFQjCNGpPVAKGyXpV6nA5ca_heN7vqcvTw)